# Is it normal for German Landlords to intercept internet traffic?

Tags: germany, internet

After reading https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/136543/landlord-will-be-watching-my-data-traffic-as-mentioned-in-the-lease-agreement I was wondering if this realy is common in germany?

From the answer:

> I would say that the restrictions are pretty standard for Germany.

Is it?

Comment: If there are german laws that make the landlord responsible for the useage, then it may well be.

Comment: This setup (someone pays for the internet, somebody else lives there) is VERY rare in Germany, except for AirBnB-like deals or dorms. This might very well be on topic.

Comment: Even in dormitories, mst students that don't use the university network have their own internet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a normal rental property, the tenant is in a contract with the telecommunications provider and landlord has no business listening to the communication.

When the landlord **does** provide internet access for tenants, he/she gets into a complicated legal position. The owner of the internet connection is generally liable for things like copyright violations, hate speech, etc. coming from that connection. This law predates open-access wifi connections and even the internet. Legislation and legal precedent are only slowly catching up with that new reality.